# typescript array of objects not inside [ ] after outside function

Tags: angular, typescript, grouping

I try to group by a data in typescript from Angular to show in table

My problem is when I console log array of objects inside GroupDataForShowIntable() function It look ok but when I console log In ngOnInit() an array of objects it go outside []

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DirectiveService } from '../services/directive.service';

const groupBy = function (xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-directive',
  templateUrl: './my-directive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-directive.component.css']
})


export class MyDirectiveComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private directiveService: DirectiveService) { }
  
  dataSource = [];
  displayedColumns: string[];

  GroupDataForShowIntable() {
    //getdata From Backend API
    this.directiveService.GetMyDirectiveList().subscribe(response => {
      if (response['operation'] == 'success') {
        const data = response['data'];
        var new_data = groupBy(data, 'directive_topic');
        Object.keys(new_data).filter(key => {
          this.dataSource.push({ directive_topics: key, isGroupBy: true });
          let values = new_data[key];
          values.filter((element) => { this.dataSource.push(element); });
        });
        console.log('InSideFunction', this.dataSource)
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('fail', err);
    }, () => {
      console.log('success');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GroupDataForShowIntable()
    console.log('OutSideFunction', this.dataSource)
    this.displayedColumns = ['directive_group_name_text', 'directive_committee_position'];
  }

  isGroup(index, item): boolean {
    return item.isGroupBy
  }

}
```

[image: Console log InSideFunction Line:36]

[image: Console log OutSideFunction Line:47]

I can't figure out why please help

I want array of objects go Inside []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not outside of the array, this is just a side effect of your debugger doing lazy-loading. When you logged the array in `ngOnInit` the array was empty, but by the time you've clicked the drop down in your debugger, the array was filled by the asynchronous `subscribe` callback.

When you logged the data inside your function, you logged it inside the `subscribe` callback, after populating the array. So of course it will already be filled when you log it.

When you click the drop-down, your debugger references the array and gets the elements. So if the array has changed since the initial log, you will see a mismatch between the first line and the actual contents.

---

From your comment the issue is that you aren't seeing your html update. That's because pushing new objects onto an array will not cause change detection to fire, this only happens if you were to reassign the entire array. Use the `ChangeDetectorRef` service to force change detection.

```js
  constructor(
    private directiveService: DirectiveService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  GroupDataForShowIntable() {
    //getdata From Backend API
    this.directiveService.GetMyDirectiveList().subscribe(response => {
      if (response['operation'] == 'success') {
        const data = response['data'];
        var new_data = groupBy(data, 'directive_topic');
        Object.keys(new_data).filter(key => {
          this.dataSource.push({ directive_topics: key, isGroupBy: true });
          let values = new_data[key];
          values.filter((element) => { this.dataSource.push(element); });
        });
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        console.log('InSideFunction', this.dataSource)
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('fail', err);
    }, () => {
      console.log('success');
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think it go outside because when I try to show it in table it empty and I test with show Output values of array It show me only [ ] In html page

Comment: Change detection won't fire by simply pushing elements onto an array. See my updated answer.

Comment: I add this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() in my code and it work like a charm thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like asynchronous time issue.

```
 dataSource = [];
displayedColumns: string[];

//flag that can be used in ngIf in template
isDataTableComplete: false; 

GroupDataForShowIntable() {
//getdata From Backend API
this.directiveService.GetMyDirectiveList().subscribe(response => {
  if (response['operation'] == 'success') {
    const data = response['data'];
    var new_data = groupBy(data, 'directive_topic');
    Object.keys(new_data).filter(key => {
      this.dataSource.push({ directive_topics: key, isGroupBy: true });
      let values = new_data[key];
      values.filter((element) => { this.dataSource.push(element); });
    });
    //Table is shown only after the entire computation is done
    this.isDataTableComplete = true; 
    console.log('InSideFunction', this.dataSource)
  }
}, (err) => {
  console.log('fail', err);
}, () => {
  console.log('success');
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I tried it and got an error in ngInit It say 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules